# How to stream data efficiently in flutter dart Streambuilder?

Tags: java, flutter, dart, stream, reddit

I'm trying to display the Reddit live comment streams in flutter API using the flutter draw package. I'm able to stream the contents inside flutter stream builder but there's a break in the continuity of the stream, some streams are skipped when I compare them to live stream outside the streambuilder. Here is the code which I'm using to achieve real-time stream display

```
// import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:draw/draw.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: RedditFlutter(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class RedditFlutter extends StatefulWidget {
  RedditFlutter({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RedditFlutterState createState() => _RedditFlutterState();
}

class _RedditFlutterState extends State<RedditFlutter> {
  var comments;
  ScrollController _scrollController =
      new ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 50.0);

  var msg = '';
  Future<void> redditmain() async {
    // Create the `Reddit` instance and authenticated
    Reddit reddit = await Reddit.createScriptInstance(
      clientId: <redditclientid>,
      clientSecret: <redditclientsecret>,
      userAgent: <reddituseragent>,
      username: <redditusername>,
      password: <reddit password>, // Fake
    );

    setState(() {
      comments = reddit.subreddit('cricket').stream.comments();
    });

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    redditmain();

    super.initState();
  }

  List item = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Reddit"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: comments,
          builder: (context, snap) {
            if (item.length > 100) {
              item = [];
            }
            // print(snap.data.body);
            if (snap.hasData && !snap.hasError && snap.data != null) {
              item.add(snap.data.body);

              return Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  itemCount: item.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Card(
                      child: ListTile(
                        leading: Image.asset('assets/criclogo.png'),
                        title: Text(item[index]),
                        trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            } else
              return Text("No data");
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this will display the stream in listview but in between like after some big length of data next sequential data goes missing which can be seen in real stream display outside the flutter, where am I doing wrong, where these data are going? is there a better way to build and display reddit stream inside stream builder?

Comment: go to https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html and read the second paragraph

Comment: How can I implement that in my case? here stream is continuous, not static like in that example integer 1 to 9

Comment: use `Stream.map` for example